# A pixel format transform logic from 32-bit pixel to 24-bit pixel by dropping all the alpha channels

Tags: pixel

I try to solve a coding problem and the problem description is in pic. 1. I find it’s hard for me to understand the format transform logic. I write down all my questions as follows. I hope someone can help me to figure out the logic.

[image]

Question:

1. It says the program should drop the alpha channel, and also mentions the beginning place of the next pixel. When I process the first pixel in the input array and drop the alpha channel in the first pixel, does the next pixel mentioned in the description is the first pixel or the second pixel in the output array?
2. About the beginning place of the next pixel, it says the next pixel starts in the 4th byte of the first 32-bit word. I’m not sure when I calculate the beginning place, I should calculate it using the original data, without dropping the alpha channel, or I should use the one I dropped all the alpha channels.
3. Also, when I calculate the first 32-bit word, should I start from the very beginning of the original input array or should I start from the alpha channel I just dropped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. It says the program should drop the alpha channel, and also mentions the beginning place of the next pixel. When I process the
>    first pixel in the input array and drop the alpha channel in the first
>    pixel, does the next pixel mentioned in the description is the first
>    pixel or the second pixel in the output array?

Neither, it's the second pixel from the **input** array. You are supposed to read the **input** array, hence the name (one 32bit block at a time). The result will be saved in the **output** array.

> 2. About the beginning place of the next pixel, it says the next pixel starts in the 4th byte of the first 32-bit word. I’m not sure when I
>    calculate the beginning place, I should calculate it using the
>    original data, without dropping the alpha channel, or I should use the
>    one I dropped all the alpha channels.

Since you have to calculate the resulting **output** array you should "calculate" the start positions in the **output** array. As you save as sequence of 3x8 bit blocks (24bit) in a 32bit array (since it is an `int` array), you will get an "overlap" on how/where the ranges/values are saved. This is indicated in the assignment like:

```
|  3x8   |  3x8   |  3x8   |  3x8   |
|--------|--------|--------|--------| 
|11 22 33,11 22 33,11 22 33,11 22 33|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|
|   int[0]  |   int[1]  |   int[2]  |
```

> 3. Also, when I calculate the first 32-bit word, should I start from the very beginning of the original input array or should I start from
>    the alpha channel I just dropped?

You do not change the **input** array at all. Instead you save the result in the **output** array and you start at the beginning at `output_RGB[0]`.